# How to install php-xml and php-mbstring on PHP 5.4.9-4?

Tags: ubuntu, php, php5

I have added the PHP5 to UBUNTU 12.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5 -y
```

and installed the PHP5

```
php5 php5-common php5-mysql php5-xmlrpc php5-cgi php5-curl php5-gd php5-cli php5-fpm php-apc php-pear php5-dev php5-imap php5-mcrypt
```

However I can't find two packages

```
php-xml and php-mbstring
```

Any idea how they are called now?

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should check the [package description](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php5/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages) for PHP from that repo.

```
Package: libapache2-mod-php5
Source: php5
....
 Description: ...
 The following extensions are built in: bcmath bz2 calendar Core ctype date
 dba dom ereg exif fileinfo filter ftp gettext hash iconv json libxml
 mbstring mhash openssl pcre Phar posix Reflection session shmop SimpleXML
 soap sockets SPL standard sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm tokenizer wddx xml
 xmlreader xmlwriter zip zlib.
```

Note that mbstring and xml **are built in** according to the description.

Comment: And I can verify through actual software setup that the libapache2-mod-php5 library does provide a functional php-xml package for the system. PHP is just really bad about their package/dependency naming.

Comment: The link 'package description' is broken.

Comment: Still suffering from _linkrot_